# Parse.com post to twitter through Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, twitter, parse-platform

Is this posible, I all ready link PFUser with Twitter account, send PFFile to class. Now I wish to post it on twitter through Cloud Code. But how? Is it even posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Twitter API to post a status update.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update

It is not clear what you want to do. I assume you want to post an image with the status update you need to learn how to upload media.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/uploading-media

With either option you will need to make authenticated posts. To do that you need to learn about OAuth.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth

What will help is to use a library which does all of this work for you. You may find `JSClient` can help. It is for Node.js but if you can get it working with Parse Cloud Code it can save you a lot of work.

https://github.com/BoyCook/TwitterJSClient